# Counting SQL Server Records and returning result by output parameters

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to count records  from multiple tables and return the results to output parameters so I can use them in Visual Studio C#.

Below is the T-SQL and C# code:

T-SQL code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE CountRecordsForUpdates
    @AreaOfLaw AS numeric OUTPUT,
    @SubjectMatter AS numeric OUTPUT,
    @Principles AS numeric OUTPUT,
    @Judges AS numeric OUTPUT,
    @Courts AS numeric OUTPUT
AS
    DECLARE @AreaOfLawOut AS numeric
    DECLARE @SubjectMatterOut AS numeric
    DECLARE @PrinciplesOut AS numeric
    DECLARE @JudgesOut AS numeric
    DECLARE @CourtsOut AS numeric
    DECLARE @CasesOut AS numeric
    DECLARE @ReportsOut AS numeric
    DECLARE @IssuesDiscussedOut AS numeric
    --DECLARE @Judgement AS numeric
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT @AreaOfLawOut = COUNT(AoLId) FROM [dbo].[CLR.AreaOfLaw] OUTPUT
    SELECT @SubjectMatterOut = COUNT(SMId) FROM [dbo].[CLR.SubjectMatter] OUTPUT
    SELECT @PrinciplesOut = COUNT(PId) FROM [dbo].[CLR.Principle] OUTPUT
    SELECT @JudgesOut = COUNT(JId) FROM LocalJudgesView OUTPUT
    SELECT @CourtsOut = COUNT(CourtId) FROM LocalCourtView OUTPUT
    SELECT @CasesOut = COUNT(CaseId) FROM LocalReportedCaseView OUTPUT
    SELECT @ReportsOut = COUNT(ReportId) FROM LocalReportView OUTPUT
    SELECT @IssuesDiscussedOut = COUNT(IDId) FROM CLR_IssuesDiscussedView OUTPUT
END
GO
```

C# code:

```
try
{
    decimal aol = 0, sm = 0, p = 0, judge = 0, court = 0;

    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(DataSources.RemoteConnectionString()))
    {
        sqlConnection.Open();

        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("[DB7934_businessmind].[CountRecordsForUpdates]", sqlConnection))
        {
            sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter aolParam = new SqlParameter("@AreaOfLaw", aol) { Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output };
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(aolParam);

            SqlParameter smParam = new SqlParameter("@SubjectMatter", sm) { Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output };
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(smParam);

            SqlParameter pParam = new SqlParameter("@Principles", p) { Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output };
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(pParam);

            SqlParameter judgeParam = new SqlParameter("@Judges", judge) { Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output };
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(judgeParam);

            SqlParameter courtParam = new SqlParameter("@Courts", court) { Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output };
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(courtParam);

            sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlCommand.Dispose();

            AoLRemoteCount = Convert.ToDecimal(aolParam.Value);
            SMRemoteCount = Convert.ToDecimal(smParam.Value);
            PRemoteCount = Convert.ToDecimal(pParam.Value);
            CourtRemoteCount = Convert.ToDecimal(courtParam.Value);
            JRemoteCount = Convert.ToDecimal(judgeParam.Value);
        }

        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred while counting cloud records, the original error is: "
        + ex.Message, "Cloud Records", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

When I run the code, I get the following error message:

> Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

I have tried all that I can think of but to no avail. I need help here. I was able to count them one by one, but that means I have to make a call each time to the database which is on the Internet and I don't think this is good for the traffic.

All I want is at one go I am able to count all the records in about 6 tables and return the values so I can assign them to properties in c# for future use.

Comment: So debug it and see on which line this happen. After check why this is DbNull, do you expect it to be, if this is expected behaviour check with `if(yourValue != DbNull)` do stuff. If not check why this happen.

Comment: In your stored procedure you never assign `@AreaOfLaw`, you assign `@AreaOfLawOut` instead, which is why the values are returned as null.

Comment: The error happens on the ExecuteNonQuery.  Okay I will go ahead and try .  Are you saying I should rather use the AreaOfLawOut in place of AreaOfLaw in the c# Code?

Comment: When I changed from AreaOfLaw to AreaOfLawOut it is now giving me expected parameter was not supplied error.

Comment: You have to change _your stored procedure_ toi fix that, not your C# code.

Comment: Why are you using numeric/decimal for counts? int/bigint seems a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

When a value is `NULL` in the DB, it will be returned as `DBNull`.  You have to check accordingly:

```
SMRemoteCount = !DBNull.Value.Equals(smParam.Value) ? Convert.ToDecimal(smParam.Value) : 0m;
```

**UPDATE:**

You will also have to make sure that you assign the return values in your stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE CountRecordsForUpdates
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@AreaOfLaw AS numeric OUTPUT,
@SubjectMatter AS numeric OUTPUT,
@Principles AS numeric OUTPUT,
@Judges AS numeric OUTPUT,
@Courts AS numeric OUTPUT

AS
DECLARE @CasesOut AS numeric
DECLARE @ReportsOut AS numeric
DECLARE @IssuesDiscussedOut AS numeric
--DECLARE @Judgement AS numeric
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT @AreaOfLaw = COUNT(AoLId) FROM [dbo].[CLR.AreaOfLaw] OUTPUT
SELECT @SubjectMatter = COUNT(SMId) FROM [dbo].[CLR.SubjectMatter] OUTPUT
SELECT @Principles = COUNT(PId) FROM [dbo].[CLR.Principle] OUTPUT
SELECT @Judges = COUNT(JId) FROM LocalJudgesView OUTPUT
SELECT @Courts = COUNT(CourtId) FROM LocalCourtView OUTPUT
SELECT @CasesOut = COUNT(CaseId) FROM LocalReportedCaseView OUTPUT
SELECT @ReportsOut = COUNT(ReportId) FROM LocalReportView OUTPUT
SELECT @IssuesDiscussedOut = COUNT(IDId) FROM CLR_IssuesDiscussedView OUTPUT
END
GO
```

Comment: You are right Sefe, The problem was from the stored procedure.  Upon following your corrections it now works as expected and am delighted.  Thanks to you all who contributed to my joy. Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: If the answer solves your problem, you should accept it, that other people with a similar problem know that.